# Can't create pandas DataFrame with MultiIndex columns from dicts with tuples as columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have this Python data structure:

```
a = [
    {
        ('Temperature', 'C'): 25,
        ('Temperature', 'F'): 77
    },
    {
        ('Temperature', 'C'): 30,
        ('Temperature', 'F'): 86
    }
]
```

I try to convert this data structure to a tab separated string like this, having 2 rows for header:

```
Temperature Temperature
C   F
25  77
30  86
```

In order to do this, I try to convert this data structure first into a DataFrame with MultiIndex columns. But I cannot do it using `DataFrame.from_records(a)` method because it returns a single index column with tuples as the names. How can I achieve MultiIndex columns instead?

By the way, I can do the reverse. When I have a tab separated file like above, I can read it with:

```
a_as_dataframe = pd.read_csv(r"C:\my_tab_separated_file.tsv", sep="\t", header=[0, 1])
```

Then convert it to records like this:

```
a = a_as_dataframe.to_dict("records")
```

What I want to achieve is the reverse of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `MultiIndex.from_tuples`

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.columns)
```

`df` is now:

```
  Temperature
            C   F
0          25  77
1          30  86
```

```
>>> df.equals(a_as_dataframe)
True
```